# How to decrypt file in java which is encrypted in .net

Tags: java, .net, encryption

I have a file which is encrypted in `.Net`. I have to decrypt that file in `java`.
I have `key` and `IV` in text file. This file in encrypted using `AES, CBC and PKCS7`.

I was trying to do that using following code.
Can any one please help me ?

```
File file = new File("myFile.txt");
String key = readFile(new File("AESKey.bin"));
String iv = readFile(new File("AESIV.bin"));
final byte[] secretKey = key.getBytes();
final byte[] initVector = iv.getBytes();
InputStream cipherInputStream = null;
final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES"), new
IvParameterSpec(initVector, 0, cipher.getBlockSize()));
cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), cipher);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int read = cipherInputStream.read(buffer);
final String charsetName = "UTF-8";
while (read > -1) {
    output.append(new String(buffer, 0, read, charsetName));
read = cipherInputStream.read(buffer);
}
System.out.println(output);*
```

It is giving exception  -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider
```

supporting AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding.

Can any one help me please ?

Comment: Do you have any reason at all to believe `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` is supported on your JDK? Have you introduced an additional dependency with that support?

Comment: Sorry Marko, I have no idea, I am using JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try to instantiate the cipher

```
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
```

which is

a) supported on the JDK;

b) [identical in effect to PKSCS7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7).

Comment: Hi Marko, This exception is not coming now. But my key is 34 byte so giving java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 34 bytes exception. No problem I will solve that. Thanks a lot.